# $C^*$ algebra generated by conjugation of an element

Tags: c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, conjugation

> Assume $\mathcal{A}$ is a unital $C^*$ algebra and consider some positive-definite element $\Psi\in M_n(\mathcal{A})$. Can we say something about $C^*(\langle \Psi^{-\frac{1}{2}}E_{i,i}\Psi^{\frac{1}{2}}:1\leq i\leq n\rangle)\subset M_n(\mathcal{A})$?

This question came up during my research. It may be very specific, but more generally, if $\mathcal{A}$ is a $C^*$ algebra and $x\in\mathcal{A}$ some positive element, are there any known results about the $C^*$ subalgebra $\mathcal{B}$ generated by $\{xa_1x^{-1},\ldots,xa_nx^{-1}\}$ with $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\mathcal{A}$?

I tried looking at some combinations of the elements (including taking $*$, products and sums) but couldn't come up with something that will help me understand the $C^*$ algebra I get.

Any help would be appreciated.